# Unable to override wp_new_user_notification in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to customize a User Notification Email Template but I'm not able to override `wp_new_user_notification`. I already tried [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin) and putting it in `/plugins/`folder and other options but still didn't worked, even the marked answer is not working. Also, I already used different plugins but it keeps on using the default email template function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the relevant code is in a link only, which renders this question useless to future visitors.

Comment: Something else is plugging it?  Another plugin perhaps? Or your plugin isn't properly activated / running?

Comment: Deactivate all plugins and try again with just the newly created notification plugin active.

Answer (score 1):

This technique does not work in theme code. Plugins are loaded first, then `pluggable.php` and lastly the theme. If your function override is in your theme, you’ll clash with the default function. You need to create a plugin and place your code in there.  Create a file called `custom_new_user_email.php` and place it in your plugin's folder with the following code adjusting whatever new body content you want in it.

```
   <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom New User Email
Plugin URI: http://localhost
Description: Changes the copy in the email sent out to new users
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Your Name
Author URI: http://locahost
Text Domain: new-user-email
*/

// Redefine user notification function
// Override new user notification function
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
       if ( $deprecated !== null ) {
            _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '4.3.1' );
        }

        global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

        // The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
        // we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

        if ( 'user' !== $notify ) {
            $switched_locale = switch_to_locale( get_locale() );
            $message  = sprintf( __( 'There\'s a new user registration on your site %s:' ), $blogname ) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user->user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __( 'Email: %s' ), $user->user_email ) . "\r\n";

            @wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), sprintf( __( '[%s] New User Registration' ), $blogname ), $message );

            if ( $switched_locale ) {
                restore_previous_locale();
            }
        }

        // `$deprecated was pre-4.3 `$plaintext_pass`. An empty `$plaintext_pass` didn't sent a user notification.
        if ( 'admin' === $notify || ( empty( $deprecated ) && empty( $notify ) ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Generate something random for a password reset key.
        $key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );

        /** This action is documented in wp-login.php */
        do_action( 'retrieve_password_key', $user->user_login, $key );

        // Now insert the key, hashed, into the DB.
        if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
            $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
        }
        $hashed = time() . ':' . $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array( 'user_activation_key' => $hashed ), array( 'user_login' => $user->user_login ) );

        $switched_locale = switch_to_locale( get_user_locale( $user ) );

        $message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= __('To set your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n";

        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

        wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password info'), $blogname), $message);

        if ( $switched_locale ) {
            restore_previous_locale();
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Already did this, as seen on the link I provided. I tried creating it as a plugin but still didn't work.

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere because I just tested it and it's working.  Follow my instructions and code and it will work.  Here is a screenshot of the modified message. http://imageshack.com/a/img922/9913/8zaQzx.png

Comment: Yes I copied the code which is the preferred method instead of linking since links can be removed.  Sorry I should have linked the original author my apologies you're correct.  I've removed the copied code and copied and pasted the original WordPress function instead. I've removed the reference to GPLv2 license